# Groovy each method on list of arrays

Tags: arrays, groovy

I met quite strange behaviour of each method on list of arrays in groovy.
I have given piece of code.

```
def list = [
    [2, "foo"].toArray(),
    [4, "bar"].toArray()
]

list.each { def row ->
    println(row.length)
}
```

Which gives me pretty expecting result in console

```
2
2
```

Then I did small modification to this code

```
def list = [
    [2, "foo"].toArray(),
    [4, "bar"].toArray()
]

list.each { Object[] row ->
    println(row.length)
}
```

And result is

```
1
1
```

Because variable row is array with one element which is my original 2 elements array from list.

Is there some explanation for this?
Im using groovy 1.8.8 or 2.1.2

Comment: Looks like it might be [similar to this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1157) where arrays were wrapped as a side-effect...  It's probably worth asking on the [groovy-user mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/groovy-user-f329450.html).  As a workaround, you could just not type `Object[]` in your each closure definition

Comment: Oddly, it also only occurs with `Object[]` it seems.  `[ ['a', 'b'] as String[], ['c', 'd'] as String[] ].each { String[] row -> println row.length }` Works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a feature rather than a bug :p

Object[] in a closure declaration has a special semantic for variable argument:

From http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition:

> Groovy has special support for excess arguments. A closure may be declared with its last argument of type Object[]. If the developer does this, any excess arguments at invocation time are placed in this array. This can be used as a form of support for variable numbers of arguments.

In your example, the argument passed to the closure will be wrapped again with a new Object array, containing `list` as the only element.

As an example:

```
def list = [
    [2, "foo"].toArray(),
    [4, "bar"].toArray()
]

def c = {Object[] args -> println args}
c(list)
```

Output:

```
[[[2, foo], [4, bar]]]
```